# Cron in Windows

Tags: php, cron, scheduler

i am using Windows and i need to schedule a php task in this. Can anyone help  me on this by explaining how to use cron here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Windows Task Scheduler - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Or you can try cron in cygwin, see [How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/)

Answer (score 4):

cron is a Unix utility (although you can get a Windows port of it). However, you should try using [Windows Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Cron is not built into Windows. However, you can use the [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx) command which you can use to add/remove tasks from the schedule.

Also take a look at [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).