# cygwin ssh batch script for windows 2008

Tags: cygwin

I configured cygwin in Windows Server 2008, now we need to implement automation
I am writing a batch script to add user to cygwin\etc\passwd file using following command

`mkpasswd -l -u %username% -p /home >> /etc/passwd`

Please help me how to execute following cmd in batch file

```
echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i 

mkpasswd -l -u %username% -p /home >> /etc/passwd
```

It's not working

Comment: How **not working** ? Do you get an error?? If so: what is it??

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing Windows and Unix in your windows batch file. The batch file is running as a Windows command, as is the mkpasswd command in it. Windows has no concept of `/etc/passwd` and will throw an error. Probably something like;

```
D:\cygwin\bin>mkpasswd -l -u testusr -p /home >> /etc/passwd
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Given what you want to do with mkpasswd I'd suggest you find a way to run your automation from within Cygwin. Perhaps setting up a [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows).