# Trouble with crontab and using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

Hi I am using the whenever gem and trying to send a daily email. For testing I set it to 2 minutes, and I have it in my schedule.rb file. It calls a task I have in a rake file. When I run bundle exec rake task_to_be_called, it runs and works. But the actual scheduling does not work. When I try to run things to find out crontab it says no such file or directory. Is there some way to get a crontab file, or do I make it? How do I test or get my scheduler to run that task?

EDIT: Thanks for the advice on sharing code and error.

In my lib/tasks/daily_email.rake I have

```
 desc 'Daily email rake task test'
task daily_email_call: :environment do
ReportMailer.with(email: "email@email.com").daily_summary_report.deliver_now
end
```

Then in my config/schedule.rb I have

```
every 2.minute do
    rake 'daily_email_call'
  end
```

When I run bundle exec rake daily_email_call it functions correctly and does the send email task. My question is how to get it to do it on the schedule. I have no crontab file. Am I even able to do this locally or would it need to be on a running server. I am using windows not Linux when I run mine locally.

Comment: you should show your code and also full error

Comment: you should debug the $PATH value I think

Comment: `I am using windows not Linux` -> so you maybe need to find out how to run cron on window at first, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063975/running-whenever-cron-in-windows).

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the file name,

lib/tasks/darily_email.rake => lib/tasks/daily_email.rake

I guess this is causing the error, `no such file or directory`

Comment: Oh thanks for the idea but no unfortunately that typo was just in my post describing it.
The issue isn't with the rake job. Like I said I can call the job via console and it performs it correctly. I just don't understand how cron jobs work and getting the schedule working. I have no crontab. Any idea? The server is running in an azure docker configuration. Any idea how to run commands, I want to tell it to update crontab. But I don't know how to run command line, it just has you upload the built app.