# how to execute this shell script

Tags: windows, shell, cron, cygwin

I have a shell script written in eclipse

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# 07/28/2006. .sh file for the Hpims Cron job.
# Runs daily.


. /db2/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile

APPHOME=/devl/prod/vehmgr/cronjob/HpimsCron
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java14
JAVA_EXEC=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
JAVAC=$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac

#export APPHOME JAVA_HOME JAVA_EXEC JAVAC
export JAVA_HOME JAVA_EXEC JAVAC

cd $APPHOME

 CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i18n.jar:/appl/jConnect/classes
/jconn2.jar:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/jndi.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/mail.jar:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/mailapi.jar:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/activation.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/smtp.jar:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/soap.jar:/appl/net/jserv-1.1.2/libexec/ldap.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/function:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2java.zip
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/devl/prod/vehmgr/cronjob/HpimsCron

export CLASSPATH


#cd $APPHOME

#$JAVAC HpimsCron.java

$JAVA_EXEC HpimsCron
```

Question is - how to execute this shell script on Windows XP. I have made changes to the HpimsCron.java file and now I need to run this shell script manually to see the changes reflected.

Comment: cron is not a windows thing, afaik. You will have to write Batch Script, and set into Task Scheduler.

Comment: Install cygwin and set all paths :) - or rewrite to bat file

Answer (score 1):

In general I'd do the following:

```
CLASSPATH=something
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:something/else
export CLASSPATH
```

Becomes

```
set CLASSPATH=something
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;something\else
```

(note, the `;` instead of `:` and `\` instead of `/`)

EDIT:

The call to dbprofile suggests another script that may not be portable and whether the app (HpimsCron) would work on Windows is also highly dubious.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin will allow you to run shell commands on Windows. This post [How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows) also explains how to get cron working on Windows under Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

This won't run under Windows, it's Unix shell specific

Answer (score 0):

You might give [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) a try. It offers a Unix-like environment on a Windows system.