# Testing magento module running cron job on windows/wamp

Tags: php, windows, magento, cron, wamp

I have a host running centOS. My website is based on Magento and it is live.

I have created a module that runs a cron job every minute.

My question is: I'm running my localhost on windows (wampserver 2.0). Before uploading my module on live host i want to test it on my local host. Is it possible to test my cron job running module on windows?

Answer (score 6):

By saying that your module "runs" a cron job you probably mean that is adds a cron job. For testing it you don't need a cron to run on your windows localhost. You can trigger all Magneto cron jobs manually by running `cron.php` in from the root directory of your Magento installation. You can do it from a browser like this `http://localhost/magento_dir/cron.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 options:

1. You can call the scripts with Windows Scheduler.
2. You can install Cygwin and define the cron tasks as in Linux. More information here: [How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows)

Comment: Could you provide more in deph steps with Step 1 as i have done that with Windows Shceduler but i don't know what it is actually doing and Magento doesn't seem to recognize any cron tasks happening

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.0.2
Open Command Prompt

Write

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\magento202\bin
php magento cron:run
php magento cron:run
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\magento202\update
php cron.php
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\magento202\bin
php magento setup:cron:run
```

replace the directory ‘magento202’ with yours

Comment: how to use the magento command on windows, windows doesn't recognize it, the official Magento site just refers to Linux for using the Magento Commands

Answer (score 0):

You can use schtasks.exe to create a new scheduled task to run as per your need.

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "Cron" /tr "php -f C:\wamp\www\pro\run.php"
```

You can find more info about the commands and the usage in the below link of my blog.

http://purusothaman.me/computers/running-cron-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows 2008 and later enter the Management MMC and access Task Scheduler under Configuration. For 1.8 Mage must add -mdefault 1 to your statement. There are changes in the cron file.

Answer (score 0):

"You can do it from a browser like this http://localhost/magento_dir/cron.php" > you will get Acces denied -> go edit .htaccess and comment lines

```
###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
##   <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.
#AuthName "Cron auth"
#AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
#AuthType basic
#Require valid-user
############################################
##     Order allow,deny
##   Deny from all
##</Files>
```