# Can I execute a .SH file in Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, scheduled-tasks, sh

The .sh script is tested and working in cygwin, but now I want to Windows to automatically run it each hour.

The file has executable permissions and now I run it like this inside the cygwin terminal:

```
cd c:/users/me/documents/myfile.sh
./myfile.sh
```

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Or execute bash via a batch

execute:

```
     call "batch_from_below.bat  "c:\user\me\documents\myfile.sh" "parameter 1, if need" "parameter 2 ..."
```

batch:

```
     @echo off
     set _CYGBIN=change-this-to-your-path-cygwin\bin

     if not exist "%_CYGBIN%" echo Couldn't find Cygwin at "%_CYGBIN%"

     REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     REM SCRIPT
     REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     set x=%1
     set x=%x:\=\\%
     set _CYGPATH_SCRIPT=%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe %1
     FOR /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%x%"') do set _SCRIPT=%%A

     REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     REM PATH
     REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     set _SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp1
     FOR /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%_SCRIPT_PATH%"') do set          _PATH_TO_SCRIPT=%%A

     REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     REM EXECUTE
     REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     %_CYGBIN%\bash.exe --login -c 'cd %_PATH_TO_SCRIPT%;%_SCRIPT% %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the System environment variable **PATHEXT** to also contain *.SH;* as a known program file extension, then associate Bash shell files with *.SH* in Windows (Google will be a better friend that I am with that :).