# How to schedule a basic unix command using sed

Tags: unix, csv, sed, scheduled-tasks

Apreciate any help and excuse me if my terminology is incorrect.

```
sed -i '1,6d;$ d' *.csv
```

This unix command, run on cygwin, will go through all the files in the directory that end with .csv. 
For each file it deletes the 1st 6 rows and the last row and that's the returned file.

**My question is how do I go about scheduling this so that it is run on a certain directory periodically?**

Note: I have a fair idea around basic unix commands. Also, I currently do some scheduling, using task scheduler in windows XP, using vbs to work on some excel files.

Comment: @Andrew Barber - how can I edit it so that it is not off topic? tks

Comment: What's the point to hold this question, looks fine for me. I don't think this topic will go to `super User`

Comment: repeat to remove 7 lines in csv file by schedule job? That means the file will be cleaned soon or later. Did you notice this?

Comment: @BMW this will only ever be run once on the file, and the file will get updated and then the script/formatting will have to be applied to it again.hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `cron` on windows which allows scheduling `bash` (cygwin) scripts too. [Here is the related Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows).

If you don't want this, you can create a `.bat` batch file with contents like

```
chdir C:\where\you\want\to\run\this\script
C:\Cygwin\Or_where\you\installed\bin\sed.exe -i '1,6d;$ d' *.csv
```

And run this batch file from the Windows scheduler.

Then there is the windows version of the `at` command which works a bit like the *nix `cron`. [Here is an explanation](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html).

Comment: tks the .bat option works for me. And I will explore the "run cron on windows" option also.