# Run Python On Windows Using Command Line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cron

I usually run Python scripts on Linux using crontab as follows:

```
*/5 * * * * run-one /home/user/Desktop/folder/myScript.py >  /home/user/Desktop/folder/myScript.log 2>&1
```

Now I need to run the same script on Windows. It should run every 5 minutes as well. Is there any way to do this using command line? I don't prefer Task Scheduler.

Comment: you should try Cygwin and following this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows

Comment: You can run it on powershell using Schtasks

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it and compare