# Installation of Cron in cygwin

Tags: cron, cygwin

When I run the following command in cygwin,

```
$ cygrunsrv -I cron -p C:\cygwin64\bin --args -n
```

I get the following error

```
cygrunsrv: Given path doesn't point to a valid executable
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You only gave a folder and not a path to the executable. Besides this I wouldn't recommend to use windows paths in cygwin, this can cause errors. You should write `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/something` instead of `C:\cygwin64\bin\something.exe`
Perhaps you are looking for an
[installation guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows), and you would like to do something like this:

Install cron as a windows service, using cygrunsrv:

```
cygrunsrv -I cron -p /usr/sbin/cron -a -D
net start cron
```