# how to run erlang project in windows?

Tags: erlang, xampp, backend

I have a Erlang project which is developed in Linux Operating System but now, I want it to run on windows machine. I installed eclipse, Erlang otp, ex-pat. but still no hope that how to run it.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, on windows if you install the Erlang from [erlang.org](http://www.erlang.org/download.html), you can start an application using the werl  (or erl) command which accept the same parameters than the linux one. So at least should show what is the linux command you want to adapt.

Comment: yeah i installed Erlang emulator its working fine, but my problem is to execute a complete module and check whether is correct or not which i cannot do in Erlang emulator because my module is importing some libraries also.

Comment: On my side I am using the standard OTP organization + Rebar for my application and their dependencies. It works fine on my Ubuntu desktop and my Win7 laptop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do fast interactive Erlang command line stuff, go ahead and use [werl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/werl.html). If you want to have an environment very similar to the Linux shell, go ahead and install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). From the cygwin command line everything is very similar to the Linux shell, including running commands like `erl`. So I suggest you invest some time learning Cygwin.

I worked with Erlang on Windows for a long time and cygwin made everything feel like Linux. One feature I did miss on Windows was crontab. It is sometimes messy to schedule stuff on a Windows server, when you are used to crontab on Linux, but now it looks like there are nice [crontab support in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows).

Comment: i installed cygwin but i was unable to get, from where to start. can u please explain more, my motive is to run my Erlang project on server side as backend

Comment: Please make this comment a more specific question. It is kind of hard to give you all details for a complete Cygwin + Elang installation on Windows here on Stack overflow.