# How to run bash scripts from cygwin terminal at regular interval (say weekly)?

Tags: linux, window

I have created a bunch of scripts in windows using cygwin and I need to run them automatically at regular intervals. How can it be done??

Answer (score 1):

You may use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) utility.

For running it under `cygwin` see:
[How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows)