# Ruby on Rails how to get started with whenever cron in Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, cron, whenever

I need to create a cronjob in windows using ruby on rails.
I am using 'whenever' gem for that but not getting proper idea about that.
Please let me know if there any alternative way for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The software utility `cron` is a time-based job scheduler in `Unix-like` computer operating systems. You can't use `cron` because you're using `Windows`. I suggest you try [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Cygwin is:

> a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide
>   functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Cygwin is not:

> a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your
>   application from source if you want it to run on Windows.

[How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows)

Comment: Can we do it with windows task scheduler ?

Comment: @Pinki I don't know that is this, don't work with windows.