# Ruby on rails how to create task that run on every 5 minute in windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, email, taskscheduler

I am new to ruby on rails
I need to create a task that should send emails every 5 minute in windows using ruby on rails,
Can anybody suggest me how can i accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this gem](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). Maybe it'll helps you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails how to get started with whenever cron in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920501/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-started-with-whenever-cron-in-windows-10)

Comment: @MikhailKatrin , that gem is working with the use of rake file, thanks a lot but its taking too much time to execute the respected task .

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the script in ruby and then use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to set it and be executed every 5 minutes.
This is an example that how it would work in linux:

**script.sh**

```
/path/to/ruby.exe /path/to/your/ruby/script.rb
```

**cron**

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Check This websites for more information:
- How to use cron in windows: [Cron for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132975/9050348)

- How to setup a cron jo in windows: [Cron Windows setup](http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00487/0/Setup-Cron-job-on-Windows-7-Vista-2008.html)