# DTS like process for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have written a query I want to run against a MySQL db every hour and then email the results to a fixed email address.  I know how to do this using DTS on SQL server but have no clue how to do it on MySQL.  Does MySQL have an equivalent to DTS.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it is running on Windows 2003 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is downloading the [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html) for SQL Server and then used CDO in VB Script to send the email.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write this using your favorite scripting language and then set it up as a cron job.

Comment: What if they are not running on Unix?

Comment: I assumed it was Linux based because it was MySQL. He didn't specify in the question.

Comment: Here is a SO question about cron equivalents in Windows. That should work if it's Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron