# How to add Cron entries to WAMP localhost in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am going to create Task Shedule in laravel 5.6 in my app. I am working with windows 7 os and my localhost is WAMP. in laravel documentation there is add Cron entries to your server as

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but I have not any idea about how to add Cron entries with My wamp localhost. my laravel file is in the desktop name as **schoolproject** then how can add Cron entries with my wamp?

Comment: you can check this `http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00487/0/Setup-Cron-job-on-Windows-7-Vista-2008.html`

Comment: Check the windows "Task Scheduler" program (built-in). You should be able to run a php script using it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701861/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-using-windows-schedule-task

Comment: This is a windows question. You should add that tag to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Comment: put that artisan command into a .bat file then fire it using windows task scheduler. cron jobs are a linux thing :)

Comment: I'm about to attempt the same as you, and I think this answer is on the right track: [Laravel - Task Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813514/laravel-task-scheduling?rq=1#comment82631126_47813792)

Answer (score 0):

### For people who run a local WAMP server and their computer isn't always awake

I spent the past couple months figuring out what would work best.

First, set up your `Kernel` class and console commands as [instructed in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#introduction).

In Windows, open Task Scheduler, and create a new task:

[image]

In the Triggers section, you can set it like this:

[image]

The action should be to run the PHP executable within your WAMP folder (using `artisan schedule:run`) as the argument:

[image]

### But then here is an important difference from [other tutorials](https://quantizd.com/how-to-use-laravel-task-scheduler-on-windows-10/) I've seen:

For any tasks that are critical, you'll want to treat them separately.

For example, let's assume you have a task that backs up your database, and you'd like to run this every single day at noon, so your `Kernel` class has this command in its schedule.

**But then you realize a flaw in this approach: if you were out at lunch a few days in a row and left your computer asleep, that noon task would have been missed, and now your backups would be quite stale.**

So, remove that daily database backups command from the schedule in `Kernel`, and instead, then create a *second* task within Windows Task Scheduler, and set the trigger like:

[image]

Then in its Settings tab, you can choose "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed":

[image]

**Therefore, even if your computer is off or asleep at this task's scheduled time, Windows will know to run the task immediately upon waking.**