# A Java Program to run at particular time of day

Tags: java, timer

Have any one scheduled a java program to run at particular time of day? Does platform make any difference? I am using Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You could of course let the Java program run constantly, and schedule the work to do there. I don't know if that's an option for you, but at least you get platform independence.
For scheduling in Java there's different options like [Quartz](http://www.terracotta.org/quartz/), java.util.Timer/java.util.TimerTask, etc. I guess there are so questions rating the different alternatives.

Comment: I am using Timer and TimerTask.

Answer (score 2):

For unix-like platforms there is cron. [This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) covers alternatives on Windows.

Comment: How can I create executable from java file? "main" method is in different java file which calls this file.

Comment: In your comment below, you say that your final target is Unix.  cron is the standard job scheduler on Unix-like systems. Compiling your Java program is a whole separate question.  You'll likely end up with a .jar that will need to be run.  If an appropriate JVM is available on your Windows system, your program execution will be similar on both platforms.

Comment: @DaveE - You are right. I will have jar file finally. I mentioned platform just for additional information. I know that confused with windows scheduling or unix scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, and you have an executable, how about using the Windows Scheduler?

**EDIT**
Since you're not actually using windows: I don't know of any way to schedule something that still runs in debug (except, of course, compiling to an executable anyway).

I'm not familiar with Unix, but [it looks like](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Unix+schedule+task&form=IE8SRC&src=IE-SearchBox) you'll need some kind of scheduler on Unix (if one isn't already installed) and do the same thing: essencially schedule the OS to call the executable- passing in whatever arguments are necessary.

Comment: Since I am testing it currently, I can't go for that option as my eventual production system is unix. So I want to make sure that the program runs as scheduled.

Comment: then why do you even mention Windows in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows task schedule to schedule your program.