# How can I measure mysql time, the time and / or load of an sql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find some measure of how long my queries are taking and the load on the server if possible.

I doubt its possible, but I would like to gain the cpu usage too.

Any ideas?

Comment: question, database and web server are the same?

Comment: No because the times taken to process a query doesn't show the cpu usage on the server. It could be a quick / big query or a slow query.

Comment: Mysql 5.6 has performance module. this may help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHP Syntax

```
$starttime = microtime(); 
$query = mysql_query("select * from table"); 
$endtime = microtime();
```

Then calculate the difference between $starttime and $endtime.

Comment: I'd vote for you, but you should only used syntax highlight for code.

Comment: As the database and the webserver are on different servers, this would not be able to distinguish if the database was going slow or the webserver.

Comment: Considering the PHP page is just waiting for the MySQL query to finish, this is probably sufficiently good to determine query execution time. It's unlikely that even a slow web server would impact the reported speed; if it were that slow, then you'd have other more obvious problems. But for reasons you've already mentioned, this won't help find CPU usage.

Comment: @Matthew, This is wall time not CPU time.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the query profiler. This may do the query time bit of what you need.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-query-profiling

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

There are various tools for seeing the load on the server

Comment: But I can't see how to output this within php ? I really want to have some error trapping in php which I can send an email if things get bad.

Comment: You could enable profiling at the beginning of the script and then do a `show profiles` query at the end. You can use the standard PHP functions that you are used to.

Comment: the link does not exist anymore

Comment: Link is broken again

Answer (score 2):

Is almost impossible given your database and web server are located differently
plus you try to achieve it using PHP

**the limitation**

- you need to have access to both servers (such as ssh)
- if you embed CPU load checking such as a exec_shell ssh into database and return `uptime` upon every query execution, is overkill

**workaround**

embed a cronjob in your database server,
periodically sent email if the server load went high

Or

at the database,
periodically sent email on current running query using
`show full processlist`

**Example to store SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST**

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...) or die('unable to connect');
$sql = "show full processlist";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql);

/* optional path is /tmp */
$fp  = fopen('/tmp/'.date('YmdHis'), 'w+');
while ($row = $res->fetch_row())
{
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
$res->free_result();
```

The above should be sufficient to dump current mysql process-list into a file.
In linux box, there are lots of commands allow user to show CPU load.
But is windows, I guess you can figure out with some search on google of SO

Comment: I'm using a shared server with my ISPs hosting package, so would I be able to distinguish which queries time / load are my fault ?

Comment: @Jules - Pretty sure your database is isolated with other. Ask your ISPs to start profiling the `show full processlist` and email you as a record or stored into server for you to access later.

Comment: @Jules - you can use the `show full processlist` using your database connection

Comment: I asked my ISP `Ask your ISPs to start profiling the show full processlist and email you as a record or stored into server for you to access later` and he said he wasn't what yo mean. We tried that command it pypmyadmin and it only should what was running at that moment in time. He has a windows server.

Comment: OMG, does it mean your hosting server is in window? If your hosting server is a linux box, ask him to set a cron that explicitly `show full processlist` on your database and pipe it into email or disk file. Anywhere, your ISP unable to trace where the load come from (a big question ONE), and the guy you contacted does not know how to setup a scheduler (a big question TWO). This is ironic.

Comment: Check with the ISP again, do they have some utilities of windows task scheduler. If the server has that, you can advise your ISP to start a task that monitor `show full processlist` every minute. The output can send as an email, or output into a location on your server. So whenever your server having spike on load, you can check WHAT are the queries that running at the same time. If there nothing significant slow query, probably your application is not the culprit.

Comment: There isn't such a task to do all that.

Comment: Pretty sure either window or linux box is capable to perform scheduler. Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron . Are you able to access and setup scheduler on your window web server ? The alternative is for you to setup a scheduler and do `show full processlist` to your database.

Comment: Yes scheduling a task can be done easily, but parsing `show full processlist` to a file(s) then stripping out just the items which are for me then emailing out isn't

Comment: Easier will be prepare a PHP script, execute the show query, iterate the results (fetch_row) and fputcsv into a file using file-name like '20101122080000'. Refer to updated results

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of information you can get about database using

```
SHOW STATUS;
```

query.

I would assume Last_query_cost variable could be quite useful for your purposes of measurements. As well as Slow_queries which will show the amount of quires which was running for longer then certain amount of time. The full list of this variables is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html 
There is also a php function [mysql_stat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-stat.php) php function which returns some database usage data. For example Queries per second could be somewhat useful. 
But to take a hold of a more certain data will require ssh access to the database.

Comment: Last_query_cost always seems to return zero. I don't have access to slow queries as it holds queries from other hosting clients. Also slow queries is zero.

Answer (score 0):

use `microtime` to measure the time required for a query.

For server load, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php . CPU usage is mostly irrelevant, because mysql will be disk-bound most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

For more detailed stats, you should use mysqli::get_connection_stats (if you use php 5.3+)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-connection-stats.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP can really only time the `mysql_query()` execution time, which includes the whole round trip, latency and transfer times. To have a break down you will need to use the MySQL profiler as mentioned already.

The following code should output the information you need to know. If you want to incorporate the profiling into your PHP process, you will have to use the profiler and select relevant fields from the `information_schema.profiling` table, but if it is just to check the performance the below should suffice.

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "my-password");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("my-database", $con);

    function microtime_float()
    {
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
        return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    }

    mysql_query("set profiling=1;");

    $starttime = microtime_float();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my-table");
    $endtime = microtime_float();
    $trans_result = mysql_query("select sum(duration) as transtime from information_schema.profiling where query_id=1");
    $transtime = mysql_result($trans_result, 0, 'transtime');
    $total_time = ($endtime - $starttime);
    $transtime = ($total_time - $transtime);

    echo 'Total time: ' . $total_time . ' secs<br />';
    echo 'Transfer time: ' . $transtime . ' secs<br />';
    echo 'Query time break-down;<br />';

    $debug_result = mysql_query("show profile cpu for query 1;");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($debug_result)) {
        echo $row['Status'] . ' (Time: ' . $row['Duration'] . ', CPU_User: ' . $row['CPU_user'] . ', CPY_sys: ' . $row['CPU_system'] . ')<br />';
    }

?>
```

Once you are happy with the performance, remove all but the MySQL query you want.