# Running "cron" job on Windows server

Tags: php, iis, cron, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Hi everyone,

I'm having a script.php on IIS server and I want to call that script automatically every x minutes. The problem is that I need to pass arguments to the script like I would do in the browser **(script.php?task=aaa)**. it seems that scheduled task ignores argument *?task=aaa*...

How can I run this script passing it some "GET" arguments?

Thanks,
L

Comment: no way is that a duplicate. totally different question..

Comment: in windows a cron job is called a scheduled task, you can find it in the control panel.

Comment: It's definitely a different question because I read that answer and few more before posting and I didn't find the answer about passing the arguments. As always the only thing I can say is: oh, well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameters into the file by invoking it like so:

```
C:\PHP5\php.exe -f "C:\PHP Scripts\script.php" -- -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```

and then you can parse argv with this function:

```
function arguments($args ) {
    $ret = array(
        'exec'      => '',
        'options'   => array(),
        'flags'     => array(),
        'arguments' => array(),
    );

    $ret['exec'] = array_shift( $args );

    while (($arg = array_shift($args)) != NULL) {
        // Is it a option? (prefixed with --)
        if ( substr($arg, 0, 2) === '--' ) {
            $option = substr($arg, 2);

            // is it the syntax '--option=argument'?
            if (strpos($option,'=') !== FALSE)
                array_push( $ret['options'], explode('=', $option, 2) );
            else
                array_push( $ret['options'], $option );

            continue;
        }

        // Is it a flag or a serial of flags? (prefixed with -)
        if ( substr( $arg, 0, 1 ) === '-' ) {
            for ($i = 1; isset($arg[$i]) ; $i++)
                $ret['flags'][] = $arg[$i];

            continue;
        }

        // finally, it is not option, nor flag
        $ret['arguments'][] = $arg;
        continue;
    }
    return $ret;
}//function arguments
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 6):

I have twice cron jobs like these on my windows 2003 server. I program a schelude task of iexplorer with the url that I can work.

For example:

"C:\ProgramFiles\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://mydomain.com/admin/index.php?action=central_alertas.php&act=1

Comment: what if he's not running an httpd?

Comment: It's a fair suggestion if the person is scripting in php.

Comment: I'm just curious: How is IE supposed to exit after running the script? Or should they have another task that closes it too?

Comment: Hi mavrosxristoforos! Yes you could schedule another task like "taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T".

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest downloading [cURL for Windows](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), as it can make the page request to your server for you. You can then use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to execute `curl script.php?task=aaa`.