# Execute a function for particular time and day

Tags: asp.net

Using asp.net, I want to run a method say `void add()` for a particular period of time, say from 9am to 6pm and also for some days (eg:7 days)

Comment: You'll have to explain a little further; are you talking about a background job that should run all the time between those hours, or are you talking about a function run on every request that should check the time and only run if the time is between those hours?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Windows version of cron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using Windows Services for something like  that.

Here some info how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are describing is not a good fit for ASP.NET per se. Performing work at given times is better suited for [Scheduled Tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task), or possibly a Windows Service (which you could create in a .NET language). You could certainly display the results using ASP.NET, but ASP.NET is primarily a way for allowing on demand interaction using a browser, not server side scheduled interaction.