# using timer within windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, timer

I would like to use a timer instead of sleep within a windows service that should perform an action at a constant interval.

Lets say that I have the following class.

```
class MailManagerClient
{

    //fields
    string someString

    //Constructor
    public MailManagerClient()
    { 
          aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
          aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
          aTimer.Enabled = true
    }
    //methode

    public bool DoSomthingIncConstantInterval()
    {
        //Do Somthing
        return true;
    }


    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       DoSomthingIncConstantInterval()
    }
}
```

And I also have a windows service with the `OnStart` method.

I understand that in the `OnStart` method I will need to start a new thread for the type `MailManagerClient`.

But how do I start the thread? Which method should be the entry point for the new thread?

How should the thread stay alive?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at quartz.net, I think it'll serve your purpose much better.

Comment: Observable.Timer in [System.Reactive.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229435(v=vs.103).aspx) is something else to look into as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are starting the timer in the constructor than all you really need to do is instantiate a `MailManagerClient` in `OnStart`. You do not need to manually create a thread because `System.Timers.Timer` executes the `Elapsed` event handler on a thread from the `ThreadPool`.

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
  private MailManagerClient mmc = null;

  protected void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
    mmc = new MailManagerClient();
  }

}
```

I should point out that it would not be obvious to the next programmer looking at your code that `MailManagerClient.ctor` is actually doing anything. It would be better to define a `Start` method or something similar that enables the internal timer.

Answer (score 1):

In the OnStart method you could have -

```
MailManagerClient m;
var th = new Thread(()=>m=new MailManagerClient());
th.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider defining a Windows Task, as explained in this SO answer: [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron). The Windows OS will take care of scheduling and threading.