# How to queue emails and send by PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

everyone

Background:
I am using phpmailer to send emails.
For a group of users to register into our system.
So the admin person click register, all the emails(100+) should be sent to their email boxes.

Problem:
The admin can not wait a long long time just for the system respond.
Also, the system will report timeout after 30 seconds.

Now, only the first 6 or 7 emails are sent successfully. Other emails will be failed to be sent because of timeout.

Question:
So, how to fix this problem?

Many thx.

Comment: Easiest solution is to save the emails in some location (specially formatted file or a database), and then have a script periodically check said repository for any pending emails and then send them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) To increase the time the script is allowed to run, also check out [How do i implement this scenario using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403521/how-do-i-implement-this-scenario-using-php/)