# How do i keep a php script active even if nobody opened the website?

Tags: php

I have a project, i need to do this

1. a desktop application sends a txt file with a number to the web server every 5 seconds
2. the web server opens that file and saves the number in a database

the thing is that i need it to work 24/7 , even if the user hasn't logged in.

the desktop application already works, what can I do?

Comment: Which os are you running the desktop app in ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a cron to do this. Here's an article explaining how to set them up in linux:
http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/schedule_tasks_on_linux_using_crontab/

In case you're running this on windows:
[What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Mac is similar to linux:
http://benr75.com/pages/using_crontab_mac_os_x_unix_linux

Answer (score 0):

use Unix Chron to plan a php job that fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not actually a web *server* function, per se, (there isn't a request to serve) you just want to run a PHP script on a pre-determined schedule.  To do that, you should run a scheduled job (cron on non-windows, Scheduled Task on Windows).

We use Windows, so here's how you set up a scheduled task for a php script to run when you need it to:

1. On the web server, from Control Panel, create a new Schedule Task
2. Set the **Run** value to wherever PHP is installed and the script you want to run:

   "C:\Program Files\Php5\php.exe" C:\webserver\scripts\myphpfile.php
3. Set the **Start in** to wherever your php file is:

   C:\webserver\scripts\
4. Set up the rest of the Schedule Task options to your needs.