# automate do something without open page

Tags: php, automation

i want make script evry 15min connect to 4 address and get new link . how i can make page for do this without open page every time and script do this automate???

php can make this script? if i need some program please advise me .

like this :

```
 $ad1='http://www.avator.com';
 $ad2='http://www.miniclip.com';
 $ad3='http://www.nikani.com';
    link1=str('http://www.','$ad1);
    do This evry 15 min on server automate
```

Comment: use `cron` if you're on *nix or any substitute if not

Comment: you should search for info about `cron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @k102 mentioned, use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). It allows you to schedule a job to occur at any time interval. If you are on Windows, check out this Stack Overflow answer: [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)