# How to get django-cron to work automatically

Tags: django, cron, cron-task, django-cron

I am trying to get `django-cron` working and its not. I followed the instruction [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cron/0.2.8) to set up my cron but the problem is that my job only runs when i type `python manage.py runcrons` on my command line and the job is not run every 5 minutes. I don't know what else to do. I have read other documents on `crontabs` and `chronograph` but am confused. Do I install crontabs along with cron or chronograph or will cron work fine with only django-cron. Also how do I get my job to run automatically. In the documentation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cron/0.2.8) I read `Now everytime you run the management command python manage.py runcrons all the crons will run if required. Depending on the application the management command can be called from the Unix crontab as often as required. Every 5 minutes usually works for most of my applications.` . What does this mean. What am I missing here. Am lost. HELP

Settings.py

```
CRON_CLASSES = (
"myapp.views.MyCronJob",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (

'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_cron',

'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'myapp',


)
```

views.py

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
RUN_EVERY_MINS = 10 # every 10 min

schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

def do(self):
    print "10 min Cron"
    theJob()
```

I should mention that am using pycharm on a windows platform to run django...

Comment: Did you find out the solution to this question?

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem leads to operating system. Webserver is not that kind of deamon that calls your cronjobs, it just handels web requests. To call periodic tasks on windows you need to use Windows Task Scheduler:

[What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Other way to solve your problem is to start celery deaemon in in celery beat mode.

http://celeryproject.org/

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

This is a harder way, if you have very simple application you don't need to use celery. But there are many cases when queues are the best solution.

Comment: Would it work if you are working in Git Bash on a Windows computer?

Answer (score 1):

Install django-crontab instead.

```
pip install django-crontab
```

Change your settings.py to include django-crontab

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django_crontab',
...
)

CRONJOBS = [
('*/5 * * * *', 'myproject.cron.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

create a cron.py file in your app directory

```
def my_scheduled_job():
   #do something
```

run this everytime you include or update your cron job.

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

run your local server to test your cron:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And you are done! :)

Comment: For some reason, it's not working for me. Could you help me with this?

Comment: I cant get this working. My job doesnt get executed. is there anything to be added?

Comment: why /5 ?  cant we write without this ? for 1 week what we have to add ?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform 'runcrons' programaticaly, like this:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('runcrons')
```

As example, i was put the above lines in my wsgi.py