# How to execute program at specific times in python

Tags: python

I want to make a program that checks the current time of the pc,

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

hour = str(now.hour)
min = str(now.minute)
```

This code gets the current time. But i would like to add additonal options, such that if the hour = 12 and min = 15 run a code

If the hour = 11, the program would wait till the hour reaches 12 and then run the code

Comment: is it really necessary for the python code to check (i.e. will it be a continuously running daemon) or could a scheduling tool like cron be good enough?

Comment: Yep use cron or if on windows read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: oops, just noticed the date on the question, not sure how it ended up the top of the main page?

Comment: @olly_uk The main page sorts by activity. Anyway, dealing with old questions is positively encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

In general, don't do this yourself. All operating systems have tools to automate periodic running of tasks, such as `cron` on *nix systems, and windows task scheduler on windows.