# Creating an automation/cronjob task for .NET in IIS 6

Tags: .net, automation, iis-6, cron

I have 4 urls (for 4 websites) on my IIS 6 server that I need to run daily (say at midnight), to process some database stuff.

The urls I want to run are like:

```
http://myserver1.com/path-to-script/filename?parameters
```

What is the best way to accomplish this on a windows/.net system. In linux I would just create a simple cronjob.

Comment: See [What is the Windows version of cron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron). You could schedule a [Wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) of those URLS. I also recommend looking at [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) which I use for stuff like your request.

Comment: Is there any other way without using Wget?

Comment: You need something that can load a http page. if you run a web browser that is already installed, you are stuck with an open browser page. Autohotkey (as I recommended above) can load a page with the `UrlDownloadToFile, URL, Filename` command, so you wouldn't need wget.

Comment: I am going to try and use TinyGet which comes with IIS 6 resources

Answer (score 0):

You can make a windows service that will do what you need. More info [here](https://code.google.com/p/ncron/)