# Cron jobs in Windows 7 using php

Tags: php, cron

I am using Windows 7 and working with PHP. I am working with a cron job for the first time so I don't know where to start.

After 20 minutes, I want the query to run and insert the value of `$i` and after 20 more minutes, I want the value of `$i` to be incremented and inserted.

I am currently using the code below:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$i=1;
$r=mysql_query("insert into test1(score) values ('$i')");
?>
```

Comment: are you sure window has cron job? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: check this http://www.nncron.ru/

Comment: @ajreal no i am not sure and thats why i am asking .......how it will be done

Comment: Windows task scheduler instead?

Comment: @doctorlove please can you explain the whole process , i will b a great help for me

Comment: AT might do it - see @ajreal comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I'm using window task scheduler, I'm aggregating about 70,000+ records every hour.

First things first, If you are using WAMP
make a file named index.php under your test folder

```
<?php
  echo "Hello from Mars";
?>
```

Next go to your command prompt and try doing this:

```
C:\WAMP\bin\php\php5.4.1.2\php.exe -f "C:\WAMP\www\test\index.php"
```

If the output is the same, we are on the right track, moving along...

1. In windows 7, go to your Start Menu type Task Scheduler
2. Create a Basic Task, just fill up necessary information
3. Set the trigger, depends on your needs
4. Select Start a program
5. Specify the program script, browse the php.exe located at your wamp folder
6. Finish

More Information: http://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/

To identify if your php is running under cli:

```
<?php
  if(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') echo 'Running CLI';
?>
```

To speed up the process of typing the php location:

1. Setup a PHP Environment Variable in your Control Panel > System and Security > System > 
   Advance System Settings
2. Click **Environment Variables**
3. In the **System Variables** select **Path** and Click **Edit**
4. Append the location of your PHP file which is **C:\WAMP\bin\php\php5.4.1.2** make sure
   that you don't forget to include the semicolon which servers to separate the paths.
5. Restart PC, in your command prompt type **php -v**

Now you can do this easily:

`php -f "C:\WAMP\www\test\index.php"`