# Execute ruby on rails scheduled job with access to database from Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, cron

I have a RoR app. I would like to execute some heavy tasks offline in order to make my app faster. I need to implement some kind of EventManager that access my events database table and executes them. This EventManager should check if there are new events to execute periodically, so I found out Whenever gem that you can integrate in your app, somehow integrates with cron, looks enough for my requirements and quite easy to use. The only problem is that as it is using cron, only works on Unix systems.

To simulate cron in windows I found Windows Task Scheduler [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) , so I can plan any script. In another post I found how to call an ruby class method with:

```
ruby -r "./secretary.rb" -e "Secretary.executeEvents"
```

The problem is that I think this approach is not that simple as Whenever (which is integrated in my app). I mean, when I execute the script manually I got this error:

```
$ ruby -r "./secretary.rb" -e "Secretary.executeEvents"
c:/dev/yanpyapi/app/models/secretary.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
```

This is my EventManager class:

```
class Secretary < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.executeEvents
    events = Event.find_by_sql("SELECT e.*
                                 FROM events e, event_states es
                                 WHERE E.execution_date <= Time.now
                                 AND es.name = 'Pending'
                                 AND es.id = e.event_state_id");

    for event in events do
      event.execute
    end    
  end
end
```

In the other hand, I found ruby DBI http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_database_access.htm

So, this point I´m missed. Can I simply do it as I´m trying to do it? Or what is the best approach to do it? Do I need to user DBI?

Take into account, this is only to test my app in development environment. My production environment will be unix, so my idea is to use Whenever. So, I would like the solution would be easier as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used rufus-scheduler which is working on windows.