# Run scheduled PHP script in Wordpress to save data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a php script that I want to run every day to persist some data in the database. 
What is the easiest way to achieve this ?

Does `Wordpress` provide some kind of scheduler event that can run some `php` code at a given time ?
Or is creating a scheduled event in the `MySQL` database the correct way ?

Thank you.

Comment: scheduled events are provided mostly by the default installation of your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on a Unix system I would recommend using [cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

If you're running on Windows please take a look at this SO thread: [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron).