# Check if user is online or not .Too many ajax requests

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, user-interface

Take look at my `users` mysql table.

```
id|active|
```

These are what `active` values means.

```
0-Offline
1-Online
2-Idle
```

- Whenever someone **logs in** i update the `active` column and set it to **1**.
- Whenever someone **logs out** i update the `active` column and set it to
  **0**.

Though it can happen like someone without logging himself out closes the browser or maybe a power cut. Then the `logout.php` is not occured and it shows that user is still active.

I want to prevent this thing. If this thing happens i want the `active` table to update to `2`. But update to `0` if user does not logs it again under ***5 hours***.

***I also dont want too many ajax request per minute.***

Comment: thats what i am asking you guys help for @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cron Solution

- Make it so every-time the user visits a page/browses the site you update them to active = 1 and put in a time=`time();`
- Create a cron script to update all users who's time is lower than a specific amount, you can have 1 cron to run every 15 minutes, which can include both queries (as it will tick those at 5 hours when the time hits)

Queries in the cron file

```
UPDATE users SET active = 2 WHERE time < (time() - 900);
UPDATE users SET active = 0 WHERE time < (time() - 18000);
```

If you need some form of real time state, say the user visits a page but does not leave it (and does not close browser), then you can create a set interval to update them, say every 15 minutes.

The key is, giving yourself some kind of average estimate. Trying to detect who exactly is online at a per second basis in realtime is not good with ajax, it is not built for that purpose and you should be looking into something like NodeJS/Websockets. If however 5, 10 or 15 minute leeway is an acceptable "guess", then its very simple.

### At query solution

**Alternatively**
If you cannot use cron (shared hosting), then you could base it completely off time rather than active state. Thus when you query to show who is online, you would do an if condition within the SQL query to determine if their active state should be a 0, a 1 or a 2, have a read up on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html for that

```
select 
    username,
    CASE 
        WHEN active_time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - 900) THEN 1
        WHEN active_time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - 18000) THEN 2
        ELSE 0
    END AS active_state
FROM users
ORDER BY active_time DESC
```

If you dont want to query offline, you could add `WHERE active_time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - 18000)`, the reason not to where on active_state is because that needs to be calculated before where can be done, whilst active_time is a field and can be filtered first before the select calculation, cutting down MySQL resources.

Store your active time with a unix timestamp, either using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())` or PHP's `time()`

This will return user with their respective active states, this is on a select though but you could filter the results purely based on time and not rely on a active state being a specific number.

Comment: @HackerManiac A cron script allows you to tell your server to run a "job" at a specific interval, in this case we would tell it to run a PHP file every 15 minutes, and the PHP file would contain those 2 queries. Have a google for "Cron" and check out http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: say i have a PHP file `cronevery5.php` containing those 2 queries.   Then how ,where  and by which method will i run this every 5 hours?

Comment: @HackerManiac You would want to run it every 15 minute to ensure idle are set more often and more visible on your site. Have a read through this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/ it will explain. You need SSH access to your server and the ability to modify crontab

Comment: i am using windows! @viion

Comment: @HackerManiac Well that is going to make your life a lot more difficult, you could look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron, alternatively I have modified my post with a SQL query you could do, if you set a time when someone is on your site, you can query by this time and define a active state within the select which you can use within the query or in your PHP after. If you tell us what your trying to do you might find this better.

Comment: see i have coded a lot damn of a website in PHP,JQUERY,AJAX....  in windows will there be an problem if i shift to linux?

Comment: @HackerManiac No problem, coding PHP on any OS is same (some minor very advance stuff can be difference such as how datatypes are handled), jquery/ajax is browser related. Linux just handles web stuff far far better due to much more wide support, packages and functionality than windows. Setting up a cron is as easy as editing a file with 1 command and its done. In windows, I have no clue XD

Comment: Windows has a task scheduler. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7 If your server is an IIS server it has a task scheduler built-in too.

Comment: @JayBlanchard can u write an answer to `how to write a cron script using task scheduler` ? And possibly how to `do the same in a webhosting server `?

Comment: You want me to write an answer about using task scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an own session handler. --> [session_set_save_handler](https://www.php.net/session_set_save_handler)
Store the sessions in a database like this: [Link](http://phpsecurity.org/code/ch08-2)

Then you can make a call with SQL to the database in the `_destroy` function, that set the `active` column to 0.

That means when the session is ended (the browser is closed, or the session is expired) the `session_set_save_handler` calls the `_destroy` function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need many ajax requests. You can execute one request per few minutes and save the time of the request in the users profile.
You can run a CRON job for a script that checks each user with status 1 (online) and if the last request time is too long ago you can change the status of the user to whatever you want.

Comment: how will i do a **CRON** JOB @banti