# Run PHP function every month

Tags: php

I need to run a PHP function every month that checks Tor Exit Nodes, I have the function, but I'm not sure how to run it every month.

Here's the function:

```
$list = "http://some-tor-list.com/torlist/";
$tor = file_get_contents($list);
```

Comment: What about a cronjob? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: You need cronjobs in linux to run your script every month. In Windows you need to check Scheduled Tasks

Comment: @Bernhard This is going to need to be as compatible as possible, would a cronjob work on every system?

Comment: @user3791747 Defnitily on any unix/linux system and on windows too but different. The cronjob is only the time rule when script is executed. On windows maybe a bit different  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, using a crontab (recommended) or a script that runs constantly (not really recommended).

Using crontab you can run a PHP script the first day of every month using:

```
0 0 1 * * php /srv/http/tor.php
```

You can edit your crontab using `crontab -e`

or you could use the [sleep](http://php.net/sleep) function like this to run every month in PHP:

```
do {
    $list = "http://some-tor-list.com/torlist/";
    $tor = file_get_contents($list);

    sleep(60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
} while(true);
```

You should read up about the syntax of [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/), it's extremely powerful.

Comment: So this PHP script would make it run only every month on both windows and linux?

Comment: It will, but it'd have to be running at all times which may not be your intended behaviour.

Comment: Will that effect anything in any way

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a "cron job".  Here is a SO question that answers how to create one:

[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: Would the same thing work on Windows? I need this to be cross-platform compatible.

Comment: This article seems pretty comprehensive - http://www.waytocode.com/2012/setup-cron-job-on-windows-server/

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem like there is a good cross platform solution to cron jobs for PHP. You'll have to set each cron us specifically for the server you are using :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cron` to complete these

if in cpanel you'll find this easily

```
0 0 * * * php /home/site/cron.php
```

Or if you have a Dedicated server you can open cron tab

Look [Here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) For the more crontab options

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a php script with the content:

```php
$list = "http://some-tor-list.com/torlist/";
$tor = file_get_contents($list);
```

And then use a [cron job to run it every month](https://serverfault.com/questions/87472/how-to-create-a-cron-job-that-runs-on-the-first-day-of-month).