# How to delete files from a tftp server periodically?

Tags: tftp

**Note:** I know that TFTP can only read and write files from TFTP server. It cannot delete files.

I have some files in a **remote** **TFTP** **server**. These files get accumulated in the server. Is there a way to remove some of these files from the server periodically so that they don't get accumulated over a period of time?

Comment: Do you have root access to your host? If so I would recommend a cron job with a bash script which could handle that for you

Comment: What if the TFTP server is in windows?

Comment: same idea, different implementation then.

Comment: For windows, you will use a scheduled task, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron