# Run developer server automatically Django/Python

Tags: python, django

Basically I want my website which is run through a local network to open every morning at 8 am without me having to start the django development server.

I'm looking to setup a script which will go into virtual env run the virtual environment and then run my django project. This will need to be done through python. I will then setup an task schedule to run the python script a certain time.

Any ideas how to structure the python code?

Pretty much I want it to do the steps below, so I dont have to. And it will need to keep the cmd console open.

```
C:\Users\James>cd desktop

C:\Users\James\Desktop>cd skillshare

C:\Users\James\Desktop\skillshare>cd Scripts

C:\Users\James\Desktop\skillshare\Scripts>activate
(skillshare) C:\Users\James\Desktop\skillshare\Scripts>cd ..\

(skillshare) C:\Users\James\Desktop\skillshare>cd src

(skillshare) C:\Users\James\Desktop\skillshare\src>python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Thanks

Comment: You need a job scheduler, such as cron

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Windows version of cron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Comment: Why don't you run it under a proper webserver, which would start automatically when the machine does?