# send mail in php automatically without interfer

Tags: php, mysql

In my project i need to send an email in php before 2 days of my account expiry date. the date is stored in mysql db, how to send.
Email shoul be send automatically from server.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$select_date=mysql_query("SELECT `date` FROM `app_users` WHERE `user_id`=1");
$fetch_date=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_date);
$date=$fetch_date['date'];
$now = date("Y-m-d"); 
$cur_date=strtotime($now);
$your_date = strtotime($date);
$datediff = $your_date-$cur_date;
$days=floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
$email="nisha.gksh@gmail.com";
$subject="Account Expiry";
$message="Your account expires in 2 days";
$headers = "From: info@datesreminder.com" . "\r\n";
if($days==2)
{
    mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to run the script from a `cron` job.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code. Without code and DB structure we can't really help

Comment: i have given my code above and i need to send mail automatically before 2 days of the date with out intreption of admin

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a [cron job](http://docs.phplist.com/SetupCronJob.html). A cron job is a scheduler -commonly used in Unix-like operating systems- to periodically execute commands.

Your PHP code could be something like this:

```
<?php
$expired_users = getExpiringUsers();
foreach($expired_users as $user) {
   sendMail($user);
}
```

Now you could setup when to execute this code by setting it as a cronjob. For this add the entry to [crontab](http://crontab.org/). You could do this by entering `crontab -e`. For example if your file should be called everyday 2:30 AM and your file is in `/usr/local/bin`

```
30 2 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /usr/local/bin/mail_to_expired_users.php &> /dev/null
```

You can use a [crontab generator](http://crontab-generator.org/) to make things easy.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132975/4003801) out if you are using a Windows server.

Comment: What is your server's OS?

Comment: what about Linux server?

Comment: Yep, you can do the same in Linux