# Scheduler Task with Laravel5 in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a doubt with the SchedulerTasks. I created the command in Laravel 5.0 called `log::company`, this command I need to be executed every second, even if website is not opened.

I have an auction, when the time of auction finish I need to change the state of the auction to 'finished', with this command I change this state, for this reason I need to use this command every second.

But I use Windows and the documentation of Laravel5.0 shows how to use with Ubuntu. I don't know which is the best option to execute this command every second.

Comment: You want to execute a task every _second_? That's quite frequent - what does it do? Most cron/scheduler systems don't operate at this frequency - they are generally every minute at most.

Comment: Yes , for example I have an auction , when the time of auction finish I need to change the state of the auction to 'finished' , with this command I change this state , for this reason I need to use this command every second.

Comment: I'd probably use a [MySQL event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html) for that - looks like it supports second granularity.

Comment: Ok , I try to find information about this now.

Comment: I am using MySQL with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CronJob to triger **php artisan schedule:run** every second even if site is not opened. But since you are on Windows you have few alternatives to CronJob. Look at [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) for more information about scheaduling tasks in Windows.

Comment: I use Windows8 , I try to find infomation about this.