# How to run Python script only during certain hours of the day?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timing

I've got a script that I need to run between 7am and 9pm. The script already runs indefinitely but if I am able to maybe pause it outside the above hours then that'd minimize the amount of data it would produce.

I currently use `time.sleep(x)` in some sections but `time.sleep(36000)` seems a bit silly?

Using Python 2.7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a scheduler like cron? Though you'd still need to have it stop itself at 9pm. Unless you also put a command to stop it into the scheduler.

Comment: `time.sleep()` doesn't guarantee that it waits for the full time specified.  It can return earlier or later, so you should at least use a while loop to wait the remaining time to the next wake up time.

Comment: Python's crontab  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use cron jobs (if you are running `Linux`).

Eg: To execute your `python` script everyday between 7 am  and 9 am.

```
0 7 * * * /bin/execute/this/script.py
```

- minute: 0
- of hour: 7
- of day of month: * (every day of month)
- of month: * (every month)
- and week: * (All)

Now say you want to exit the program at 9 am .

You can implement your python code like this so that it gets terminated automatically after 2 hours.

```
import time

start = time.time()

PERIOD_OF_TIME = 7200 # 120 min

while True :
    ... do something

    if time.time() > start + PERIOD_OF_TIME : break
```

Comment: Running on Windows, but the second section helps.

Comment: @eug1712 Try to look for `cron` alternatives for windows. Eg:The Windows "AT" command is very similar to cron. It is available through the command line.
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a scheduler like cron. However, if the script is going to run indefinitely, I think `time.sleep(36000)` is acceptable (or `time.sleep(10*60*60)`).

Comment: It will run indefinitely, but how reliable is `time.sleep(10*60*60)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the time functions to check what time of day it is, then call your script when you need to:

```python
import time
import subprocess

process = None
running = False

while True:
    if time.daylight and not running:
        # Run once during daylight
        print 'Running script'
        process = subprocess.Popen("Myscript.py")
        running = True
    elif not time.daylight and running:
        # Wait until next day before executing again
        print 'Terminating script'        
        process.kill()
        running = False
    time.sleep(600)  # Wait 10 mins
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. And if you're going to do this sort of thing, you should use a scheduler.