# Schedule CasperJS script for daily execution on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, casperjs

I have a CasperJS script which works. My question is how can I schedule it to run at a specified time every day?

Could not find any good solutions online... Is there any way without using spooky?

Comment: That's not something a CasperJS script should be concerned about. Since you say that you're on windows, then this should get you going: [What is the Windows version of cron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Ok, but is it possible to use `AT` like this : `At 10:00:00AM "c:\users\me\ casperjs script.js"` ?? Or somethink like this, sorry for the syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cron job if you are running a *nix server.

For example you want your script to run everyday at 04:20, run this command :

```
crontab -e
```

then add this line :

```
20 4 * * * /your/command
```

Comment: I am on windows... Any windows solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use [Schtasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx)