# How to schedule emails according to a given date

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, scheduling

I am supposed to send an automatic e-mail through the system using PHP codeigniter on the Windows platform.

I have to schedule an email, which is automatically sent, for instance at a birthday of a person.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, however SO is not a place for tutorials / guides :) Google it, there are plenty of guides out there.

Comment: I would personally write a php script to check the current date versus birthdays in a list then set a cron job to run the script once a day checking for birthdays and sending emails if it falls on the current date. Buts thats just me.

Comment: I was googling about this but never come across with a suitable one. Thanx .. :)

Comment: Ohh thank u very much... This is really helpful for me

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale: CRON is not an option on Windows.

Comment: Is it possible to have it without using commandline? because my project iS STILL RUNNING THROUGH xampp server

Comment: @DTH, correct and sorry about that Cron is not an option on Windows so setting a scheduled task would be the rout to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is Possible. You will need to have a script that will check for today's Bitrhday's and send mails to the users.

Then You need to schedule this script to run everyday at a fixed time. You can achive this by setting a CronJob in your system. I think you have some kind of [Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) for Windows Platform but i have been working with UNIX so i am not sure about windows.

Also You will have to take a look at : 
[Running CI Script from CLI](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html)

Comment: Thread for alternatives to cron jobs in windows can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: Can just set a scheduled task in windows. Very simple to do.