# Auction site Timed out event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I am creating an auction site in which the auction has a particular end date/time.
I have a javascript timer displaying the remaining time to the user and when this countsdown it fires and event to update the back end mongodb database to say the auction has completed and it informs the winning user and fires a CLOSE function.

How would you recommend doing this for auctions that aren't physically open in a browser at the time so the Timer event never creates this CLOSE event.

Comment: The timers should have no relationship to a user's browsers. They should all be done on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this approach at all. Once I was working on a website and I needed to implement auctions. The project was in php so I wrote a php script which checks all auction rows in the database and looks for those with the timeEnd >= current time and sets their status to closed(The auctions table had int column for the status).

Then I set that php script to run as a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) once every hour. So now the server automatically runs this **server side** script every hours and checks for out-dated auctions. The interval depends on the business logic of the app. For this project the auctions could only end or start to the beginning of every hour. This approach is far better than using javascript code that triggers the server script. One reason is that you can't trust client side code. Hackers could potentially get access to that javascript file and easily modify it. You should never let your server code depend on your client side code.

However, note that my approach is not the most ideal because depending on how much auctions your db have, the server script will still need time to process it and might take from a few seconds to couple of minutes to execute it. 
For example if you have some auction that ends at 10:00:00 and the server script start executing at 10:00:00 and it takes 40 seconds to execute, the users could potentially find a way to place bid on those auctions in the interval of that 40 seconds. Your client side code should only take care for resetting the interface right at 10:00:00 so that users are not able to place bids. However, you should also make sure that the server-side code that handles your POST requests for placing bids, should also check if the auction end time is in the past before proceeding. If it only checks the status of the auction (opened or closed) it might get auctions that are ended with their status set to opened. The reason is that the cron job might still be processing the auctions and changing their status.
Another similar approach is to create service that runs on operative system level (probably c or c++ app) that would run constantly in the background and do the checks. 
The good thing with the first approach is that most of the hosting companies already offer setting up cron jobs. One example is [Bluehost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/411).

For setting up windows based "cron jobs" read additional info on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

I hope this makes it more clear to you how to handle the auctions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. You helped me so much. I decided to go with node-cron.