# Commit and push automatically on certain hour or date with Git

Tags: git, automation, push, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to **commit** and **push** automatically on **certain hour** or **date** with **Git**?

I personally use the client **SourceTree** in **Windows** operating system.

Comment: Why would you want to commit automatically? In the spirit of Git, commits act as *meaningful* steps in the progress in a project, not merely what the project looked like at some arbitrary time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a cronjob

[see e.g. here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

that does this for you...

**EDIT**

For windows alternatives to cron, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I use **Windows**. Your answer would be very useful in **Ubuntu**, Linux.

Comment: Edited my post to take this into account

Comment: I can read how to schedule a task that runs every N hours, but I'm not very sure what would be the exact command.

Comment: `git commit -a -m "Automatic commit"; git push` ?

Comment: That's the command to **commit** and **push**, but it refer to the **Schtasks** command.