# Self executable python file

Tags: python

Actually, I am new to python and I want to download some content from a website daily. So what can I use to run that file each day? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Unix based system, you may put daily [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). 
Also there are some alternatives for Windows : 
[What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)
In this way script that you want will be automatic executed.