# Batch to go back and forth between 2 exe

Tags: batch-file, exe, timed

I am trying to write a bat file to go back and forth between 3 executable files every 2hrs.

So that A&C will run for 2hrs and close then B&C will open up for 2hrs and continue this process for 24hrs. Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron may help.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you to do is to create two batch files and by using task scheduler you can control the timing (e.g every 2 hours)
start with a termination command for the running executable, delay it a little bit (in case it takes them some time to close) and execute the wanted exe's