# Laravel testing a task scheduling

Tags: laravel

My development server is my Windows computer, and I want to test the task I created before using it to my server on real users.

I know about the windows Task scheuduler but it's very limited, and I want to run my task for example, right now and test it before uploading.

What's the best solution for making sure the task is allright before using it in the server?

Comment: I know this may be a stupid reply, but most of the things about this are already given in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling).

Comment: Wrap the actual logic in a Job. Then test the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should always unit test your task, just invoke the methods in your task from within your test methods.

**Task**

```
$this->dispatch(new SendWelcomeEmail($user));
```

**Test method**

```
Mail::send(new SendWelcomeEmail($user, $view));
```

You can also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) to know which task scheduler you can use to test your command in some local integration tests.

The easiest altogether is to make a virtual machine that resembles your production server and just test the tasks in there.