# php: how can a php script restart itself when run in CLI?

Tags: php

I am running a CLI windows php script which is mostly a LOOP with some CMD exec functions.
Problem is that these exec functions sometimes hangs up.

Can this script kill itself and restart itself ? '(for instance every 5 minutes)

Comment: When a system hangs it can't do anything so as i think you need to write an extra script which scans the running process of this file and when it finds like this process has been idle for 5 mins restart it

Comment: Use a task scheduler like cron or a process manager like supervisord.

Comment: Using cronjobs would be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Answer (score 0):

> Can this script kill itself and restart itself?

Not really, yet you can run another instance of itself and then quit the current one.

> these exec functions sometimes hangs up

Then script cannot break from this by itself other by timeouting (see [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)). Or you need to have separate watchdog to monitor your script and restarting it when needed.

> (for instance every 5 minutes)

Rework your code to not loop and use cron or other scheduler (see [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132971/1235698)) to invoke your code periodically.

Comment: "Not really, yet you can run another instance of itself and then quit the current one.": how ? with an external software or inside the script itself ?