# laravel cron job windows

Tags: php, laravel-5

Iam trying to develop a cron job for a command to send email. I am completely new to cron jobs so I dont really know how it works.

Trying the command by myself in the console works perfectly. But when a set a cron job in CPANEL its not workingrs. I am using Laravel 5, can anyone help please?

Thanks!

My cron job: php /home/reporting/public_html/bsk/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

#### My Kernel.php

[image]

#### My class emailUser

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the command directly from your terminal to see if there are any errors?

Comment: You might have to set the absolute path for php.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you copy&paste `text code`, instead of posting links to pictures?... Those links will expire sooner or later :(

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron might be usefull. Also need to provide full path to PHP in your CRON command.

Comment: @Jerodev yes I already try command by the terminal and it works perfectly

Comment: Now i receive      this error  Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' email:user > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &

                                                                                     
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]                                   
  The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

Answer (score 1):

**In Cpanel:** (cPanel & WHM version 62)

Follow the menus : *Home* → *Advanced* → *Cron Jobs* and add :

```
php /home/reporting/public_html/bsk/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For Reference : `/home/user/public_html/index.php`

**On a Unix/Linux Server:** use the cmdline `crontab -e` to enter the cron editor and add the line :

```
* * * * * php /var/www/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i didnt understand  what you meen by For Reference --->/home/user/public_html/index.php

Comment: that is example or sample url sara

Comment: Now i receive this error:
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' email:user > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &

                                                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]                                   
  The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

Answer (score 0):

Cron Job will not work, if you are about to schedule the command as once a day (i.e., 00:00) iff, same time is **not** reflected in a `$schedule->command();` object

If the commands were incorrect, I used to get this warning in my Email as

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'magickwand' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.37
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

In `Kernel.php` you should specify

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('SyncAPIOrders:orders')
               ->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
               ->dailyAt('00:00');
}
```

You should add the command from the cPanel server as

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/xyz/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /home/xyz/public_html/log_laravel 2>&1
```

This will keep all the logs in `/home/xyz/public_html/log_laravel`

```
Running scheduled command: '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' SyncAPIOrders:orders > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```