# django_cron run only once django

Tags: python, django, cron

Sorry for my english. I new in django, i want send email every 1 min. I found this [solution](http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) i follow it. But my django_cron run only one.

i installed django_cron like this: `pip install django_cron`

then i added app to `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ..
        'django_cron',
'accounts',
    ...

    ]
```

and add to settings:

```
CRON_CLASSES = [
    "accounts.cron.MyCronJob",
]
```

then run `python manage.py migrate django_cron`

in app `accounts` i create file `cron` and add this code:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule


class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'accounts.cron.MyCronJob'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        print("send message")
        message = render_to_string('cron_file.html', {
            'name': '111'
        })
        mail_subject = 'Congratulations'
        to_email = 'test@gmail.com'

        email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
        email.send()
```

then run `python manage.py runcrons`

but message send only once when i call command `python manage.py runcrons`

Comment: Does the cron daemon run on your machine?

Comment: @ger.s.brett thanks for unswer. I run cron like this `python manage.py runcrons` .What are you mean?

Comment: Are you running this on a linux system?

Comment: @ger.s.brett no, im use windows

Comment: Cron does not work on windows. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron).

Comment: @ger.s.brett wow, thanks!