# Collect information from API periodically in python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way in python to create a program that runs automatically at a given time?

Specifically I need to create a program to collect information hourly from an API from 6:00am to 00:00pm so do it manually seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using Windows 10

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/132975/6622587

Comment: @eyllanes Thanks you. It was very useful.