# How to make the bat file invoke the python script at regular time?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python script.(For example, test.py)I want to start at 00:00am every day and execute this python script every 15 minutes.

I want to use the bat file to call python script.

How should I write the bat file?

I haven't written a bat file before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run you python script every 15mins, perhaps you should consider setting up a scheduled task (the Windows equivalent of cron).

See this question for more info: [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

Comment: I can write scheduled task.But now,I was asked to implement it with bat.

Comment: For example,I can write python code "schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(call_A)",but I was asked to implement it with bat.

Answer (score 0):

One quick implementation for the Python script to run every 15 minutes is to use an infinite loop with 'While'. Instead of relying on a batch file, you can have your python script wait 15 minutes before running again.

```
import os, time, sys, datetime

while True:         # Use WHILE = True for an infinite loop

        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

        print('''
                RUNNING PYTHON SCRIPT EVERY 15 MINUTES
                PYTHON SCRIPT INITIATED AT %s
            ''' % timestamp)

        # ENTER PYTHON SCRIPT HERE

        print('''
                PYTHON SCRIPT COMPLETED AT %s
            ''' % timestamp)

        time.sleep(900)  # 900 seconds = 15 minutes before next run
```

Comment: I can write python code,but I was asked to implement it with bat.