# Moving files at intervals

Tags: file, command, move

I am a real novice compared to people on here but I am able to navigate the command line and perform basic actions like move, copy, delete files and folders using the relevant commands. I am aware of the ability to use batch files and I was wondering if anyone coyld help me solve a problem at work. I dont work in IT by the way but I just know there has got to be an easy solution to this from the experience I do have.

Without going into the specifics too much my question comes down to this. I need to move one file at a time(basically a split pdf) from one folder to another at the rate of one per hour. So there may be up to 20 files all in one folder then one gets moved one hour, another the next and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Just windows 7 thanks

Comment: I'm no windows 7 expert, but a quick search tells me the solution to this might be a little more involved than you might think. Check this link out: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/advanced-users-task-creation-task-scheduler?utm_source=7tutorials.com&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=7_Tutorials_Redirect

Comment: you could check out this question, should get you on the right track https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: Thanks a lot schu34. Like I say I really appreciate this. I will read this article you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Cron's function is to run a certain command on a certain interval. To move a file once per hour you would use a [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) which is a file that specifies what to run and how often to run it. your cronfile might look somthing like this `0 * * * * <your move command>`. The to execute the cron you'd do somthing like `contab /path/to/your/crontab/file`

Comment: That would work for linux, but the OP specified windows 7 in the comments. cron doesn't work with windows does it? I though it was a unix thing.

Comment: Yup, you're right, that comment was posted while I was typing my answer :D

Comment: Guys thank you for taking time out of your days to try to help me. I really appreciate it from both of you 01010011. Thanks for your suggestion. I will read up on this. At least I have been pointed in the right direction. I just hope its not too far over my head!!