# PHP file_put_contents at specified time

Tags: php

I have a php file that points to a url like so:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

The thing I would like my php file to do in addition to pointing to the URL is write a file to the server at a specific time each day -- let's say 6:00pm (18:00).

From my initial research, the write file part seems straight forward

```
file_put_contents('todaysDateData.txt', $_GET['url']);
```

However, figuring out how to call `file_put_contents` each day at a specific time is throwing me for a loop.

**Question:** Is it possible to write a file in the manner described above at a specific time each day in native php? Ideally I would like to name the file with today's date and "Data" suffix (i.e. Mar-29-2018.txt).

**Edit**

Going from the suggestions below, I have researched `cron`: I think the syntax for my use case is:

```
0 18 * * * path/to/my/command.sh
```

I think the date syntax is correct, but I'm still confused as to how `cron` is used with my php file. Should I change the `sh` file extension to `php` since I'm using `file_put_contents`? Or is this `cron` date thing going in my php file itself and I have to make a `.sh` (whatever that is?)

Comment: You're looking for cron

Comment: Or if you're on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: CRON can run any file you just give it the command you would use in the shell to execute e.g. `php file.php` to have PHP execute a file named `file.php`.

Comment: @chris85 Just to clarify, `php file.php` there is a space between `php` and the file name right? The comment had the line over two lines so I couldn't quite tell for sure. If I understand it correctly, it's like the first item is the code language.

Comment: What I did was enter this at the shell: `php path/to/my/file.php` I hope that was right, I guess I will find out at 6:00pm...

Comment: Yup that should be right. That assumes `php` runs PHP for you on the command line. If `php path/to/my/file.php` works for you in the shell it should work from the CRON as well, assuming you are using the same linux user.

Answer (score 1):

You can check timetamp and file name.

```
<?php

$todayHour = 18;
$todayMinute = 0;
$timeCreate = mktime($todayHour, $todayMinute, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$todayFilename = 'data-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.txt';

if (time() >= $timeCreate && !file_exists($todayFilename)){
    // Code input content file here
    file_put_contents($todayFilename, $_GET['url']);
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants the script to be executed at a specific time every day.

Comment: @Mike Thank sir, I'm wrong